# Show $g(x)=e^x\ln(x)$ is onto

Tags: calculus, analysis, exponential-function

I need help proving the following theorem:

> $g(x)=e^x\ln(x)$ is onto

This is very intuitive, as $g$ is continuous and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$, but I don't know which theorem I could use here.

Comment: Did you learn the intermediate value theorem? It is a powerful tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$, there exist $a > 0 ,b < \infty $ such that $g(a) < y $ and $ y < g(b)$ (these follow from $\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$ respectively).

The intermediate value theorem tells us that there is some $x \in (a,b)$ such that $g(x)=y$. In other words, given any point $y \in \mathbb{R}$, there is some $x$ in the domain $\mathbb{R}^+$ that maps onto it, as required.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

You use the intermediate value theorem. Your limits shows that it takes arbitrarily largely positive and largely negative values - the intermediate value theorem says it takes all values inbetween.